# undefined variable in a function in PHP?

Tags: php

I created a function called multiply() that takes an array of numbers, multiplies each value by a number and return the array:

```
<?php
  function multiply($arr, $factor)
  {
      $newArr = array_map(function ($number) {
          return $number * $factor; // line 5
      }, $arr);
      return $newArr;
  }
  $array = [2,4,6];
  $factor = 2;
  $result = multiply($array, $factor);
  print_r($result);
?>
```

The output:

```
Undefined variable: factor .... on line 5
```

I don't understand why `$factor` is undefined in my case?

Comment: The anonymous function used in your `array_map()` has it's own scope and `$factor` is not available with your anonymous function's scope.

Comment: please checkout http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php to read more about it

Answer (score 3):

The function used in array_map has a different scope and it can't see variables outside of it. You need to use a `use` keyword and pass $factor as an additional argument so it will be available:

```php
$newArr = array_map(function ($number) use ($factor) {
    return $number * $factor;
}, $arr);
```

Comment: I add 'use' to my code, but it says "syntax error. Unexpected use..."

Comment: Try use `(&factor)`